# java- Object swaping between ReadOnly and Writable

Tags: java, readonly

I'm struggling with the following task:

Create a class Person which has at least the attribute name.
When created the object is in read-only mode 
(only getters are allowed).
By using the method unlock, which requires a password, the object goes in read/write state. 
It is important, that the **compiler checks if the object is used correctly** (depending on the current mode). **Do not use flags**
A read only object must not be copyable.

I think I can do the last one, but have no idea how to do the compiler-checks.
Any hints?

Comment: "current" mode would only be known/changed at runtime. so, how's the compiler supposed to check it?

Comment: this is some homework assignment, isn't it? why did you add the `generics` tag. you question doesn't mention generics. is your exercise about generics? ;-)

Comment: @user829755 It is a task form last year OOP exam. I have an exam next week so I try to solve old ones,  I'm not sure if have to use generics I guess I need them for the compiler checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generics would be helpful like this:

class `InternalPerson` extends `PublicPerson` which has name as a field. `InternalPerson` has a setter for the name but `PublicPerson` has only the getter. normally you operate on `PublicPerson` but the unlock method gives you the `InternalPerson` object.

not really safe since you can always cast `PublicPerson` to `InternalPerson` but maybe good enough for the exam?

Comment: I tried this and it works great. No problems with casting since you can't cast a parent to a child class. Thanks :)